# monodroid app crash at start but its working on emulator?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

i have only a tabhost and 2 tab. my app doesnt work on my device. (HTC Wildfire, Android 2.2)

However its working on my emulator. Can anyone solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: can you debug your application while running in device and post the logcat also post the source code

Comment: i think its not about codes. i blocked all code and its still not working and how can i open logcat in vs2010 ?

Comment: View -> Other Windows -> Android Device Logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure to rebuild your project after activating your copy of MonoDroid?  The evaluation version does not support deploying to a device.